# how to find the volume of the Revolved Domain about z Axis [ volumes ] [ integrals ]

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, jacobian, cylindrical-coordinates

> **let $D$ = {$(x,0,z) | (x-1)^2 + z^2 \leq 1$} find the volume of the body obtained by revolving $D$ about the $ Z $ axis**.

how do i solve this with integrals ( triple / double ) .

intuitive solution **( might be wrong )** is to find the area of $ D $ on the $XZ$ plane which is $\pi$ and to sum the disk around the circule {$ x^2 + y^2 = 1$}
 right ? 
so my guess the answer is $ 2\pi ^2 $ .

not sure how to solve it

Comment: I am puzzled by "revolved around the z-axis".  For every y, the figure is circle with center at (1, y, 0) and radius 1.  Rotating that about the z-axis fills the circle with center at (0, y, 0) with radius 1 so area $\pi$.  However, since there is no bound on y, the **volume** is infinite.

Comment: sorry they told us that each point  on D is  $(x,0,z)$ at first

Comment: @Mather, why did you multiply the area of $D$ by $\pi$? The perimeter of the circle is $2\pi r=2\pi$

Comment: you are right yet when i get a cylinder and slice it into rectangles and sum the rectangles i get that the volume of a cylinder is $ 2\pi R * RZ $ which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

The volume on revolving $D$ is $8$ times its volume $V$ in the first octant, due to symmetry.

The equation of the surface generated is $(r-1)^2+z^2=1$, where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. The centre moves along the circle $r=1,z=0$.

The required integral is $8\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^2\sqrt{1-(r-1)^2}\ rdr\ d\theta=2\pi^2$.

Note that you could have arrived at this intuitively. The area of the cross-section is $\pi$. Multiply that with the 'length' of the torus, which is given by $2\pi r_{avg}=2\pi$ and you get $2\pi^2$.

[image: Figure]